# Spring Restful service is only returning English characters but other characters except English is displayed as '?'

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller

I have built a Restful web service using `Spring MVC 4.0.1`. The controller is returning response of every English words and characters in a browser. But every individual character that are `NON-ENGLISH` are being returned as `?`.
For e.g. for `नेपाल` (Nepali word pronouncing `Nepal`) it is returning as `????`.

Here's my `RestController` class:

```
@RestController
public class TestController {

private final ApplicationContext applicationContext;

@Autowired
public TestController(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
    this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
}

@RequestMapping(value = {"/test/{test}"})
public String getLatestCategoryNews(
        @PathVariable("categories") String categories,
        @RequestParam String test)
{
    return "नेपाल";
}
}
```

Here's my `dispatcher-servlet.xml`:

```
     <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.billions.news.web.controller"/>
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

Here's my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1"
     xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>    
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

Here's my application-context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd>
    <context:property-placeholder location="application.properties"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.test.web"/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter" />
```

When I return reponse converting it to the json string using json-io, in IDE console I can get the desired text. But when I receive the response in Browser it gets converted back to '????'. It annoys me a lot.

I used following too on `@RequesMapping`:

```
method = RequestMethod.GET,
        produces = MediaType.ALL_VALUE
```

But it still produces the same response with '????'.

I tried loads of solution out there on the web including `filters`. But none of them helped.

I am using tomcat as a server.

Is there a way so that I can get response in any language out there including English in spring-mvc restcontroller.

EDIT:

Following solved the issue:
All I had to do was to replace

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

with

```
    <mvc:annotation-driven >
    <mvc:message-converters>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter">
                <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
            </bean>
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all, in your controller's method `getLatestCategoryNews` you are returning `String`, this means that spring will pick one of the registered `HttpMessageConverters` which in your case will be `StringHttpMessageConverer` ([here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/StringHttpMessageConverter.html) is the doc) which will be responsible for writing the returned `String`.

By default charset for this `StringHttpMessageConverer`

> default constructor that uses "ISO-8859-1" as the default
>   charset.

you should override this message converter's charset.

simply register bean:

```
<beans class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <array>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter">
                <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
            </bean>
        </array>
    </property>
</beans>
```

UPDATE from me

you should also set project encoding in maven pom.xml

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
```

Update from @Computergodzilla

I had to do was to remove `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` with

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
   <mvc:message-converters>
      <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter">
         <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
      </bean>
   </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

Comment: Thank you Nikolay. Isn't the first tag should be <bean> instead of <beans>. Tomcat threw an error 'Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 21; columnNumber: 98; cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'class' is not allowed to appear in element 'beans'.'. But still I am getting ??, when I registered above bean.

Comment: Sorry to say, I am not using maven. :(

Comment: which version you are using? i think spring cannot find registered message converter. see this link - http://spring.io/blog/2011/02/21/spring-3-1-m1-mvc-namespace-enhancements-and-configuration/ - Registration of HttpMessageConverters

Comment: Thank you Nikolay. The link helped.  All I had to do was to remove <mvc:annotation-driven/> with '<mvc:annotation-driven >
        <mvc:message-converters>
                <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter">
                    <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
                </bean>
        </mvc:message-converters>
    </mvc:annotation-driven>'. Please update the above answer with above snippet and I will accept and upvote your answer. Thank you. You are awesome.